# Python for loops output into list

Tags: python, list

```
def factors(n):
for i in reversed(range(1, n+1)):
    if n % i ==0:
        print(i)
```

This code currently outputs the factors of a number in a new line ex. factors(18) outputs 18 9 6 etc.... How can I make it so when I type

```
print("factors for 18 are:", factors(18))
```

Returns a list of

```
factors of 18: [18,9,6,3,2,1]
```

Without having print(i) in my function.

Comment: So basically your question is just "how do I create a list of numbers instead of printing the numbers"? Do you know about the `return` statement?

Comment: BTW, this algorithm is ok for small n, but it gets pretty slow for large n. A simple way to improve it is to save pairs of factors, i and n//i. So if n is a million, you only have to test i upto 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def factors(n):
  ret = [] #Make an empty array to store number factors
  for i in reversed(range(1, n+1)):
    if n % i ==0:
      ret.append(i) #append factors
  return ret #return array of factors

print("Factors of 18", factors(18))
```

Comment: I may be doing something wrong but when I run this program I get Factors of 18 [18]